# How to exclude unsafe deletions in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, static-analysis

On a large project, I ran the "Unused declaration" inspection, looking for unused methods. It found several hundred and I chose to safe delete them.

IntelliJ analysed each method (again?!) and concluded 16 usages were potentially unsafe to delete. That's fine, I'm happy to be cautious. However, I'm not clear what I'm supposed to do now.

How do I tell IntelliJ "***OK, I believe you. Delete everything else.***"?

If I press "Do refactor", it deletes them anyway. If I right-click on the usages and press "Exclude" or "Remove", it still deletes all the methods.

[image: intellij screenshot]
<sub>These options do nothing</sub>

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Create an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Comment: But before you create a bug report you can give this question a little bit more time. There are some developers from JetBrains active on Stack Overflow who have an eye on tags like [tag:intellij-idea], so they maybe will come around and maybe have an answer for you.

Comment: Running 192.6262.58 and have the same issue (reported to be fixed in the ticket?). I tried to safe delete lot of stuff reported by analyze report, got "Potentially unsafe.." issues. Ok, fine but I want to delete the stuff that is safe to delete. Marking all unsafe issues as "exclude" seems to mean that "delete these anyway". So the question remains, how to delete stuff that is safe to delete and keeping the stuff that is not safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the issue created for the reported problem at YouTrack:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-208211
Thank you